# Can't find tag or library described for http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat8, java-ws

I have created java web service with this settings.
[image: Create Java Web Service]

After created with out any error popup so many file with red cross mark, I have opened the files and error showing on this line

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Development Environment
Fedora 25,
Tomcat 8.5,
Eclipse Neon,
Axis2 1.7.5 binary,
openjdk version "1.8.0_131"

Answer (score 0):

Add `jstl library` in your classpath or add its dependency in `pom.xml` if using maven

Comment: how to add jstl library to class path sorry i really don't know how? how do i check i am using maven or not?

Comment: I have downloaded the standard-1.1.2.jar from http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/taglibs/standard/1.1.2/ and jstl-1.2.jar  from http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/ , i added these 2 jar inside Wen_Inf -> Lib, after this no error i can create web service but when i run the web service i am getting the following errors  Servlet.init() for servlet [AxisServlet] threw exception